# convert date to a specific format and pass to a file in unix

Tags: unix

I have requirement in unix. I have a file which has the end time of a workflow like the below:

```
End Time:[Thu oct 05:12:12:12 2017]
```

I have to convert this to  mm-dd-yyy hh24:mi:ss and write to another file.

Please let us know how can i do that?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
grep input_filename -e "End Time:" | sed -E 's/End Time:\[\w{3}\s(\w{3})\s([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})\s([0-9]{4}).*$/\1-\2-\6 \3:\4:\5/' | sed 's/jan/01/ig; s/feb/02/ig; s/mar/03/ig; s/apr/04/ig; s/may/05/ig; s/jun/06/ig; s/jul/07/ig; s/aug/08/ig; s/sep/09/ig; s/oct/10/ig; s/nov/11/ig; s/dec/12/ig' > output_filename
```

This is broken into three commands. First is `grep` to extract the line with the time you need. Second is `sed` to rearrange the date into the output format, but note that the month is still a string. The third command is another `sed` call and this replaces the month name with a number.

Caveats:

- the above regex are rather strict and will fail on simple deviations
- no need to split the regex stuff into two `sed` invocations, this could be handled in one
- or for that matter, the whole process could be more gracefully handled with python, perl, etc

Comment: Thanks a lot @BurnsBA. Let me check this once.